# How can I include regular expressions in webdriver backed Selenium RC?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm having problem automating to type the text in the textbox with variable id's using Selenium RC with Java. Strange thing is that, the code below worked fine in Selenium RC with C# but not with Java.

```
selenium.type("xpath=//input[matches(@id,'.*firstName')]", firstName);
```

worked on Selenium RC with C# but not with Java.

I also tried these options after looking in some stackoverflow posts but it still doesn't work

```
xpath=//input[@contains(@id,'firstName')];
xpath=//input[@contains(@id,'.*firstName')];
xpath=//input["id=regexp:.*firstName"); 
css=input[id^='regexp:.*firstName'];
css=input[id^='firstName']
```

Here's the Xpath code for the text box.

```
<td>
 <input type="text" class="textboxbase" id="mymainfirstgenid_13_mainsecond:firstName"      style= "width:160px; "tabindex="0">
</td>
```

I used (.*) as regular expression for the variable id in Selenium C# which works fine but doesn't work in Java. Also i can't use class and name as parameters because they are same for all the fields. Only each element has variable id's.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with your XPath expression? I would have thought that the problem is that your second argument to `type` is just `.*firstName`; doesn't it need to be `".*firstName"`? That is -- doesn't it need to be a string, wrapped in double-quotes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment ruakh, yes that was a typo error. the second argument is "firstName" which i declared as firstName = "John" or sth. When i run the code in eclipse it gives an error saying: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]://input[matches(@id, '.*firstName')] at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrErrororg.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention that it gave an exception! I thought it just failed to find the element you wanted. You should post the full stacktrace -- and also the details about the version of Selenium you're using.

Comment: Thanks ruakh again. Most of the exception error are the same that i posted.I'm using selenium stand alone-sever-2.20.0 .jar file.                                                          com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]://input[matches(@id, '.*firstName')] at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrE‌​rrororg.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestRefe‌​rence.java:50)

Comment: Selenium is open-source, so a *full* stacktrace would help if anyone wants to look into the source. You can edit your question to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
css=input[id^='firstName']
```

is for the BEGINNING of a string.

For the end of a string use this:

```
css=input[id$='firstName']
```

Comment: regular expressions aren't allowed in the CSS3 spec. WebDriver just uses what the native browsers support. For reference I typically look at this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#selectors

Comment: Thank u very much TunaBum. That worked fine. However, do you know why the Xpath's are not working? The code that i posted above works fine in Selenium with C# but not in Java.

Comment: xpath=//input[contains(@id,'firstName')];
ditch the "@" before contains
there's also an endswith function in xpath. But I dislike xpath and css is more translatable to UI developer's (not to mention people generally see CSS selectors perform faster than xpath).